# SalesForce CTI adapter redo

Tags: c#, salesforce, adapter

I have just been tasked with making a CTI adapter for SalesForce to communicate with our own systems.... but our systems are completely non-standard and built internally. I have spent ONE day only with this project!

First of all, we are not c++ developers, only C#.
Secondly, we require only a very basic set of functionality. We already have a fully working SIP phone with all the custom functionality our clients require.

Here is the scenario:

> Customer launches their SIP phone (provided by us), and the phone logs
>   in etc etc. Instead of having to press the dial pad buttons, they want
>   to be able to use the SalesForce interface to "click to dial", hang
>   up, call, dial, transfer, etc.

We can modify the phone to accept commands probably by opening a port and accepting HTTP commands, that's no problem.

So as you can see it would be:

> [SalesForce.com (browser window)] <--> [CTI Adapter (to be built)] <--> [SIP Phone
>   (already built)]

Clearly the only part that's required is the CTI Adapter, but their provided sample Toolkit is in C++ and seems overly complicated, for such simple functionality.

I have used fiddler is monitor some of the communications on localhost:11000 and there seems to be basic too and from XML.

**So some questions:**

Is it possible to produce a simple CTI without their Adapter?

How does the CTI work on a technical / low level basis? Like for example, so far is see there is a call with "?getXML=true....". Is that the basic way that XML is sent to the browser?

If something changes on the Adapter, like the line goes to in-use, how do you send the message back to the browser? is there some kind of poll? i can imagine that the Adapter can call methods in the browser document.

Any other assistance would be great. Or even just a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1) Theoretically speaking it is possible to produce a simple CTI without their Adapter but believe me this is an enormous project. Actually [SalesForce.com (browser window)] <--> [CTI Adapter (to be built)] <--> [SIP Phone (already built)] is not exactly accurate. I suppose there is also a CTI server involved so that communication with PBX can take place.  CTI Client communicates biderectionally with CTI server. Cti server also communicates biderectionally with PBX. So client want to login and request this from CTI Server. CTI Server send the request to the PBX and asks for example to login the phone with number 3016 to a certain group of PBX.

2) How  CTI work on a technical / low level basis?  The XML is not the lowest level layer for the CTI technology. Probably your CTI uses CSTA protocol. This is the low level basis protocol for the communication of CTI Server with a PBX. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-supported_telecommunications_applications. Supposely, you study CSTA and starting experimenting you can make your own implementations but this is also an enormous procedure!!

3) for the third question I suppose the provided documentation will explain it but probably if the line goes in-use then CTI Server will hear this from PBX and will send an event to the CTI Client. So the communication also involves events that you have to catch.

The right direction from my experience is to understand the architecture of your installation. This involves SIP phone, CTI client, CTI Server, PBX and the way that the communication is taking place.

Finally I know that it seems a very complicated task (actually it is) but as soon as you study the architecture you will start to hope!! There are a few companies providing CTI implementation but the architecture is the almost the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. With little response from anywhere, and with Wireshark in hand, we simply rolled up our sleeves and build the thing our self. Yes, as you said it was an "enormous procedure"